# Result of using millions of malloc()s and free()s in your C code?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I was recently asked this question in an interview.

Suppose there is a large library of **C** programs and each program constantly `malloc()`s and `free()`s blocks of data. What do you think will happen if there are a million calls to `malloc()` and `free()` in one run of your program. What will you add to your answer if you have been given a very large memory heap storage?

Comment: I believe they wanted to hear the key phrase "memory fragmentation".

Comment: I'm guessing that's what they wanted to hear, too, but depending on the program's malloc/free pattern, it might not have that problem at all. (I'm also not at all sure how the answer changes if the "memory heap" is "very large".)

Comment: @SteveSummit It might be even completely wrong if we assume different `malloc/free` implementations. For instance FreeRTOS have 3 different implementations in the box, one of these have `free` doing nothing. So the correct answer would be - we will run out of memory very fast.

Comment: Interesting what is the meaning of "very large"

Comment: If you have a very large memory heap, you may be able to perform memory block `coalescing` when memory is returned to the free list.  You could also do this is the heap is small, but intuitively, I think that it is more likely to be successful with a larger heap.

Comment: @EugeneSh.with the larger heap, I am just guessing that the frees are more likely to return adjacent memory locks.  I'm just guessing though.

Comment: @bruceg `void free(void *memblock);` does not return a value.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's true. When free is called, the underlying memory management system may be able to coalesce adjacent blocks in the free list.  There is no action required by the caller.

Comment: You might also want to read about `jemalloc`: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919/

Comment: You could always have your own malloc/free which uses something like the buddy algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation).  Not very efficient in terms of memory usage but great for excessive processing of free lists etc.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that may happen is that your memory will be fragmented, especially if you allocate block of different sizes.

Thus, if your memory size is not large, some malloc may fail, even if the total free memory is bigger that requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a stupid question without more qualifiers. Suppose you do

```
 for (;;)
 {
    free (malloc(SOMEVALUE)) ;
 }
```

In that case very little is going to happen.

Let's assume that mallocs and frees occur in a random order. If you have an malloc implementation that uses fixed sized blocks, you are going to get a different result than if you use one with variable sized blocks (=memory fragmentation).

The result you get is entirely dependent upon the malloc implementation and the sequence of the calls to malloc and free.

Comment: After reading all comments - I'm pretty sure the recruiter wanted to hear "memory fragmentation" in my response.